# JavaScript promise with .then inside .then doesn't work

Tags: javascript, promise

### Current state:

I have the following function in a link builder which is using a configuration service which returns a promise with some enviroment parameters:

```
_createLink: function (label, args) {
   return LinkBuilder.builder()
      .withLabel(label)
      .withUrl(ConfigService.getConfig()
         .then((env) => env.baseUrl 
                      + TranslationService.instant('MY.URL', args)))
      .buildLink();
},
```

A few explanations:

- `withUrl(...)` does the following:

```
    withUrl: function (param) {
                        if (typeof param === 'string') {
                            builder.value.linkUrl = param;
                        } else if (typeof param === 'function') {
                            builder.value.linkCalculationFunction = param;
                        } else if (typeof param === 'object' && typeof param.lazyBuildUrl === 'function') {
                            builder.value.linkCalculationFunction = param.lazyBuildUrl();
                        } else if (typeof param === 'object' && typeof param.then === 'function') {
                            builder.value.linkCalculationFunction = () => param;
                        } else {
                            throw new Error('invalid url param ' + param);
                        }
                        return builder;
                    },
```

- `withLabel(label)` will set a label which will be displayed as the URL text

`withLabel: function (label) {builder.value.labelKey = label; return builder;}`

- `.buildLink()` is just returning `builder.value`, with the URL and all other params:

`buildLink: function () {return builder.value;}`

- `TranslationService` will find the `'MY.URL'` entry in a JSON file with translations. The value will be something like `'http://www.myserver.com#name={{name}}&age={{age}}'`. The `name` and `age` parameters from `args` will be inserted there.

### Problem:

I need to encode those `args` using an external service which also returns a promise and then to append the return value to my link. That external service will return something like `'data': {'encodedId': '123-456-789'}`, and my final link should be: `http://www.myserver.com#encodedId=123-456-789`. Here is what I did:

### My original attempt:

In the JSON file with translations I removed the parameters from the entry, so now it's only:
`'http://www.myserver.com#'`

The `_createLink` function now looks like this:

```
_createLink: function (label, args) {
   let content = {
      'name': args.name,
      'age': args.age
   };
   return EncodingService.saveContent(content)
       .then((data) => {
           return LinkBuilder.builder()
              .withLabel(label)
              .withUrl(ConfigService.getConfig()
                  .then((env) => env.baseUrl 
                               + TranslationService.instant('MY.URL') 
                               + 'encodedId=' + data.encodedId))
              .buildLink();
},
```

When I place a breakpoint at the last `then` line, I see that I have the correct `data.encodedId`, the correct `env.baseUrl` and the `TranslationService` is also correctly returning the JSON entry. But for some reason, I don't see the link in my page anymore. I guess that I'm doing something wrong with chaining the `.then`s, but I'm not sure what.

### Another attempt which still doesn't work:

Here is the third version, which still doesn't work:

```
_createLink: function (label, args) {
       let content = {
          'name': args.name,
          'age': args.age
       };
       return $q.all([
          EncodingService.saveContent(content),
          ConfigService.getConfig()
       ])
           .then((data) => {
               let url = data[1].baseUrl
                       + TranslationService.instant('MY.URL') 
                       + 'encodedId=' + data[0].encodedId;
               return LinkBuilder.builder()
                  .withLabel(label)
                  .withUrl(url)
                  .buildLink();
    },
```

Again, I placed the breakpoint at the last `return` statement and there I have the `url` formed correctly...

### Usage of `_createLink`:

This function is used like this:

```
getLeadLink: function (label, access, address) {
   return myService._createLink(label, someService._createArguments(access, address));
        },
```

...and `getLeadLink` is used in a component like this:

```
this.$onInit = () => {
...
   this.leadLink = OtherService.getLeadLink('LINEINFO.LEAD.LINK', someData.access, someData.address);
...
};
```

...and `leadLink` is then displayed in the HTML file.

Note: None of these things was modified, so the usage of `_createLink` and the displaying of the link is still the same as it was before.

Comment: What is `LinkBuilder`? Does it handle Promises in `withUrl`? Because `.then()` still returns a Promise, not the text the Promise will resolve to.

Comment: Note that your first `_createLink` and your updated one return **different** things. Your first one returns the result of `buildLink`. Your updated one returns a *promise* that will be fulfilled with the result of `buildLink`. (At least, as far as we can tell, the updated `_createLink` is incomplete in the question.) That means you have to use them differently unless `buildLink` returns a promise.

Comment: I edited the question and added the implementation of `buildLink` and `withUrl`

Comment: Your `withUrl` function is called with a promise as argument. I don't think it deals correctly with that. You cannot expect to have access to the URL that is only available in some future. You just have the promise.

Comment: But it worked properly in the old version...

Comment: Then use the old version? That just means the old version dealt with asynchrony correctly. Now you have a synchronous chain where each method call returns the original object. That is synchronous. The embedded `then` callback will be called *after* the last method call

Comment: I would, but now I have to use this encoding service for all the URL params...

Comment: I added the new attempt where I use `$q.all` hoping that I would have all the necessary data before creating the URL... Still doesn't work.

Comment: Your third attempt with `all` should work fine. What exactly is the problem? Does the caller of `_createLink` expect it to return a promise?

Comment: @Bergi I updated the original question again, there you can see the whole chain.

Comment: In all your attempts you seem to keep thinking you can create a function that can return the link. This is not possible, as you have asynchronous tasks. You must stick with the promise (asynchronous) pattern.

Answer (score 2):

The third attempt is going in the right direction.

There is however no way you can get the *future* URL *now*. And so any attempt that in the end expects a simple function call to return the URL cannot be right. Such a function (like `_createLink`) is deemed to return before the asynchronous parts (i.e. any `then` callbacks) are executed. In your third attempt you improved things so that at least `_createLink` will return a *promise*.

Now remains to await the resolution of that promise.

So, any wrapping function execution around `_createLink`, should take into account the asynchronous pattern:

```
getLeadLink: function (label, access, address) {
   return myService._createLink(label, someService._createArguments(access, address));
},
```

This is fine, but realise that `_createLink` does not return the URL, but a promise. And so also `getLeadLink` will return a promise.

You write that you want to display the URL, so you would do something like this (I don't know how you will display, so this is simplified):

```
OtherService.getLeadLink('LINEINFO.LEAD.LINK', someData.access, someData.address).then(function(builder) {
    var $link = $("<a>").attr("href", builder.value.linkUrl)
                        .text(builder.value.labelKey);
    $(document).append($link);
});
```

The key message is: don't try to get the URL as the return value of a function. It does not matter how many wrappers you write around the core logic; it will remain an asynchronous task, so you need to get and display the URL asynchronously as well. You'll need to do it in a `then` callback, or use `await` syntax, which makes anything following it asynchronous code.

Comment: Hi @trincot, thanks for the response. Let's say that I don't know how this URL will be used/displayed later (and sincerely, I don't know for sure). What would be the solution in a slightly modified case, when I have access to two JS methods only. The first one is using `EncodingService.saveContent(content)` and needs to pass the `encodedId` from the returned Promise to another method which will add that parameter to the URL. After that, I have no control of the URL. What would be your approach?

Comment: Whatever you do, you need to access the promised value asynchronously. it is always the same principle.